# Regex to use as validation for disabling more than 2 letters in a row

Tags: regex

I need a regex that checks if there are more than two letters.

It should only allow one letter.

But allow numbers.

For example

- 1a is good
- 1ab is bad
- 11 is good
- 11ab is bad

I have one, it also takes as wrong when there are any numbers... I do want to allow numbers. Just not more than one letter.

This is my rgex:

```
export const onlyOneCharacter = (string) => {
  return /^[A-Za-z]{0,1}$/.test(string) ? undefined : "wrong";
};
```

Returning undefined mean its correct, so it doesnt show any validation error.

Comment: Why not use `/[A-Za-z]{2}/` and return appropriate value based on the result?

Comment: Because I didnt know this was possible.

Comment: I posted solutions for both scenarios, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be no two *consecutive* letters in the string, you can use

```js
const texts = ["1a", "1ab", "11", "11ab"];
const onlyOneCharacter = (string) => {
  return /[A-Za-z]{2}/.test(string) ? "wrong" : "correct";
};
console.log( texts.map(onlyOneCharacter) )
```

If you need to check for two letters that are not necessarily consecutive, you can use

```js
const texts = ["1a", "1ab", "11", "11ab"];
const onlyOneCharacter = (string) => {
  return /[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]/.test(string) ? "wrong" : "correct";
};
console.log( texts.map(onlyOneCharacter) )
```

Note that `[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]` regex searches for a letter, then zero or more non-letter chars, and then a letter anywhere inside the string.

If the pattern is matched, the result is `wrong`, else, the return value is `correct`.

Comment: The first regex will not work correctly if we check with `a11b`. You're checking for consecutive letters.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan That is why there are two solutions. See "*2 letters in a row*" in the title.

Comment: You probably forgot to add `^` and `$` for your second solution as the `.test` method returns `true` if founds any matching substring.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
^\d*[a-z]?\d*$
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tXCAnz/1)

##### JavaScript Example

```js
const onlyOneCharacter = (string) => {
  return /^\d*[a-z]?\d*$/.test(string) ? undefined : "wrong";
};

console.log(onlyOneCharacter("1a"));
console.log(onlyOneCharacter("1ab"));
console.log(onlyOneCharacter("11"));
console.log(onlyOneCharacter("11ab"));
```